# MySql PDO - How to fetch "newest rows from group" when using GROUP BY, ORDER BY and INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

> ```
>       products_table:             | p_id  | name  |
>                                   | 1     | name1 |
>                                   | 2     | name2 |
>                                   | 3     | name3 |
>
>
>       favourites_table:           | id    | p_id  | deleted   | group_id  |
>                           fetch-> | 1     | 1     | 0         | 11        |
>                                   | 2     | 1     | 0         | 11        |
>                           fetch-> | 3     | 2     | 0         | 22        |
>                                   | 4     | 2     | 0         | 22        |
>                           fetch-> | 5     | 3     | 0         | 33        |
>                                   | 6     | 3     | 0         | 33        |
> ```

```
    $sth = $db->prepare('   SELECT a.p_id, b.name

                            FROM favourites_table AS a
                            INNER JOIN products_table AS b
                            ON a.p_id = b.p_id

                            WHERE a.deleted=0
                            GROUP BY a.group_id
                            ORDER BY a.id ASC
                            LIMIT 0, 10;');

    $sth->execute();


    while(($query_data = $sth->fetch()) !== false) {
    echo $query_data['p_id'] . ':' . $query_data['name'] . '<br>';
    }
```

This query fetches rows 1, 3, 5 from 'favourites_table'.

How to change it so it fetches "newest rows" (2, 4, 6) ?

Do I have to change the whole query or am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm, how do you know it is selecting id 1,3,5 when you are not including the `id` column in the `SELECT` list? Given your sample data, it shouldn't matter since values of `p_id` are repeated.

Comment: Change it from ASC to DESC would do I guess..

Comment: use `ORDER BY b.id DESC`

Comment: ...I suspect though that you're running into a common misunderstanding of how MySQL does `GROUP BY` aggregation, wherein it allows you to have ungrouped columns in `SELECT` and somewhat indeterminate results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confused by the pernicious misfeature in MySQL called the `GROUP BY` extension. Read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html

You want the rows you define as *latest* for each value of `group_id`. These rows are in fact the undeleted ones with the highest `id` values.

So, first you need to use a subquery -- a virtual table -- to find those rows, as follows:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id, group_id FROM favourites_table WHERE deleted = 0 GROUP BY group_id
```

Then, you need to use that resultset to find the right rows in your main query. You would do this like so:

```
SELECT a.p_id, b.name
  FROM favourites_table AS a
 INNER JOIN products_table AS b ON a.p_id = b.p_id
 INNER JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(id) AS id, group_id FROM favourites_table WHERE deleted = 0 GROUP BY group_id
            ) AS c ON a.id = c.id
 GROUP BY a.group_id
 ORDER BY a.id ASC
 LIMIT 0, 10
```

This should get your results.

Question: Why order them oldest (lowest `id` value) first? Why only show the oldest ten results? Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you mr.Jones! :) Great, this was exactly what I ment and your example worked! I only needed to change LINE 3: "INNER JOIN products_table AS b ON a.p_id = b.p_id" to fetch matching p_id from 'products_table'

Comment: Mr.Jones, answer to your question: This was just an example I wrote here. ORDER BY DESC/ASC in the example is irrelevant. Problem was that I didn't understand GROUP BY. But now I do a little. Thank's again!

Comment: Ooops, forgot the `ON` clause for the first `INNER JOIN`.